# надо в массиве найти максимальное значение

Tags: массивы

```
#include<ctime>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main() {
    int arr[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {


            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << " \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: И в чем заключается вопрос/проблема?

Comment: надо найти максимально число которое генерируется

Comment: @Maxym Необходимо найти максимальный генерируемый элемент внутри какого массива? Одномерного или двумерного? В примере у вас просто генерация и вывод многомерного массива. Дайте пожалуйста конкретное условие

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```
int mMax = arr[0][0];

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
         if (arr[i][j] > mMax)
             mMax = arr[i][j];
```